# Please Help me to solve the Simple Java program

Tags: java, user-input, java.util.scanner

The assignment is:

Write  a  program  that  provides  20%  discount  for  member  who  purchase  any  two  books at XYZ bookstore. (Hint: Use constant variable to the 20% discount.)

I have done the coding, but cannot prompt book name, and then show the discounted price. Please see my coding below and modify it as your needs.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Book_Discount {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
  public static final double d = 0.8;
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  int purchases;
  double discounted_price;
  System.out.print("Enter value of purchases: ");

  purchases = input.nextInt();
  discounted_price = purchases * d; // Here discount calculation takes place

  // Displays discounted price
  System.out.println("Value of discounted price: " + discounted_price); 
  }

}
```

Comment: Where's the code that attempts to get the book name? You're managing to read an int, so you should be able to figure out how to read a string. What other problem(s) do you have exactly?

Comment: The only ingredient you are missing is `scanner.nextLine()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For prompting the book name as well, you write something like:

```
/* Promt how many books */
System.out.print("How many books? ");
int bookCount = scanner.nextInt();
scanner.nextLine(); // finish the line...
double totalPrice = 0.0d; // create a counter for the total price

/* Ask for each book the name and price */
for (int i = 0; i < bookCount; ++i)
{
    System.out.print("Name of the book? ");
    String name = scanner.nextLine();  // get the name
    System.out.print("Price of the book? ");
    double price = scanner.nextDouble(); // get the price
    scanner.nextLine(); // finish the line
    totalPrice += price; // add the price to the counter
}

/* If you bought more than 1 book, you get discount */
if (bookCount >= 2)
{
    totalPrice *= 0.8d;
}

/* Print the resulting price */
System.out.printf("Total price to pay: %.2f%n", totalPrice);
```